# JQuery not hiding the buttons upon ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

When I try to use the below code with jfiddle, I comment out the jinja and the buttons hide as expected, but in the browser, the input buttons don't hide

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div>
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
        <dt>Stock Ticker:
        <dd><input type=text size=30 name=stockname>
        <dt>Date:
        <dd><input id="datePicker" type="date" name='start_date'>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Add>
      </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
</div>
<div>
<form action="{{ url_for('edit_entry') }}" method=post class=edit-entry>
  <table class="entries">
    <tr>
    <th>stock ticker</th>
    <th>date bought</th>
    <th> Edit</th>
    </tr>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <tr>
        <td><h2>{{ entry.stockname }}</h2></td>
        <td>{{ entry.start_date|safe }}</td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Edit"/>
        <input class="show" type="button" id="edit-button" value="Edit"/>
        <input class="hide" type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Cancel Changes"/>
        <input class="hide" type="submit" id="save-button" value="Save Changes"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
    {% else %}
    <em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(today);

    $(".hide").hide();
}); 
</script>
```

and layout.html consists of...

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Flaskr</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h1>Flaskr</h1>
  <div class=metanav>
  {% if not session.logged_in %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">log in</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">log out</a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZNTf/

Comment: Show the fiddle. Also, it's best to hide DOM elements with CSS.

Comment: add fiddle, and showed it using classes

Comment: My answer updated with fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You are defining lots of

`<input type="submit" id="save-button" value="Save Changes"/>`

in your for loop, so you have multiple input tags with the same id on the page, thus it does not work. Try giving the inputs a class instead.

Comment: what happens with id's in fiddle is only one of the buttons hides, but in the browser, nothing hides.

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id for your input elements.

```
<input type="hidden" class="name" value="Edit"/>
<input type="button" class="edit-button" value="Edit"/>
<input type="button" class="hide" value="Cancel Changes"/>
<input type="submit" class="hide" value="Save Changes"/>
```

Change the selector to use class.

```
$("input[class=hide]").hide();
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZNTf/1/

Comment: it works in fiddle but not in my browser.  It's something else, something too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Id's need t be unique. If you would like to hide multiple elements with the same name use a class.

```
<button class="hide">Cancel</button>
<button class="hide">Save</button>
```

Then add a css class to hide them. It's more reliable IMO.

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i think the issue is associated with the dom / jquery selection, as opposed to just finding a way to hide it.  I'm trying this test case as a means to debug more jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with localhost not property reading in jquery -_-

"//url" instead of "http://" or "https://" only works remotely